# Will last semester grades before applying for PhD programs affect my chances?

Tags: graduate-admissions, grades

I'm a student studying Industrial Engineering at a strong public research university in the US well-known for engineering, especially my field.  I'll be applying to PhD programs this upcoming fall but have concerns about my current semester's grades.

My performance before this semester has been solid (3.8+ GPA, Dean's list all semesters, only 3 Bs in non-major related courses) and I have been told my application is very strong (Goldwater Scholar, 1-2 publications, 7+ presentations, 2-3 years of university research, compelling extracurriculars, close relationships with recommenders who are well-known in their field).

However, this semester there is the chance I'll make a C in one of the hardest classes for my major.  I don't have any excuse for this, I simply underestimated a highly weighted midterm.  I'm trying my hardest to not have that happen, but how would it affect my chances if it did?

I'm particularly interested in how it would look when applying to a non-IE program, as I'll be applying for Stanford's Aeronautics and Astronautics PhD program - two professors have labs at the intersection of aerospace and IE that align well with my research.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty unlikely, though not impossible that a late, lower, grade would affect anything. Most decisions are made already before final semester grades can be made available.

It also seems to be the case that some final semester chaos is expected by those interviewing and making decisions. They probably went through something like that themselves, making applications and future planning.

But it is what it is. Perhaps talk to your professor to see what you need to do to bring it up a bit.

If you apply *only* to Stanford then you might be disappointed. It is much better to cast a wide net for graduate study, rather than a narrow one.

Comment: Oh, I haven’t applied yet — I’ll be applying this fall.  I’ll definitely be talking with my professor to see what I can do to improve, but I appreciate the reassurance.  I will be applying to two other programs, my home lab (which has already given an unofficial return offer) and another institution with a professor I know well.  I’m not putting all my eggs in one basket!